# excel currency data changing according to regional setting

Tags: c#, mysql, excel

Facing an issue, I have two columns in MySQL table. One is in currency English format(1.0000) and in German(1,0000), but when I exporting the data from export to excel(custom), my currency column data is not coming as it is in the database.

Example- if regional setting is English(U.S)
->Currency(In English format)-- 1.0000(correct)
->Currency(In German format)-- 10,000(wrong)

if regional setting is German(Germany)
->Currency(In English format)-- 10.000(wrong)
->Currency(In German format)-- 1,0000(correct)

I want my data as it is exist in my table.

Is there is any thing which can be done from excel side or any suggestion in C# side?

I have used

> cultureInfo.Invarientculture

but with no result.

This is the code used to create the Excel file:

private string ExportToExcelFile(DataTable dtTable)
    {

```
    string tab = "";
    StringBuilder sbldr = new StringBuilder();
    if (dtTable.Columns.Count != 0)
    {
        foreach (DataColumn col in dtTable.Columns)
        {
            sbldr.Append(tab + col.ColumnName);
            tab = "\t";
        }
        sbldr.Append("\n");
        foreach (DataRow row in dtTable.Rows)
        {
            tab = "";
            foreach (DataColumn column in dtTable.Columns)
            {
                string temp = row[column].ToString();
                string txt = temp.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                if (column.ToString() == "Currency Rate(English)")
                {
                    NumberFormatInfo nfi = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).NumberFormat;

                    // Displays a value with the default separator (".").
                    // Displays the same value with a blank as the separator.
                    nfi.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
                    //var priceAsDecimal = Decimal.Parse(temp, NumberStyles.Currency);
                    //string priceAsDecimal1=priceAsDecimal.ToString("C");
                   // double number = Convert.ToDouble(temp);
                   // string a=number.ToString("G", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    //sbldr.Append(tab + a);
                    sbldr.Append(tab + txt.ToString(nfi).Replace("\n", " ").Replace("\n\r", ";").Replace("\r", " ").Replace("0", "0"));
                    //sbldr.Append(tab + a.Replace("\n", " ").Replace("\n\r", ";").Replace("\r", " ").Replace("0", "0"));
                }
                //else if (column.ToString() == "Currency Rate(German)")
                //{
                //    string txt = temp.ToString(cultureDe);
                //    sbldr.Append(tab + txt.ToString().Replace("\n", " ").Replace("\n\r", ";").Replace("\r", " ").Replace("0", "0"));
                //}
                else
                {
                    sbldr.Append(tab + row[column].ToString().Replace("\n", " ").Replace("\n\r", ";").Replace("\r", " ").Replace("0", "0"));
                }
                tab = "\t";
            }
            sbldr.Append("\n");
        }
    }
    return sbldr.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Where is the code? What "Export to Excel" command do you refer to? Numbers in SQL or C# *don't* have formats by the way, they are binary values. Is this a text field perhaps that simply contains a string that looks like an English-formatted number?

Comment: I have added the code below.

Comment: Post the code in the question itself, don't add it as an answer. What I see though isn't creating an Excel file at all, it creates a tab-separated file. Use a library like EPPlus to create a *real* Excel file.

Comment: The provided code worked for me. thanks

Comment: my date field is like '01/07/1975 00:00:00' but in excel it comes '26115
'(any random value). I have tried to format like below but no result-           using (ExcelRange col = ws.Cells["O1"])
                {
                    col.Style.Numberformat.Format = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss";
                    col.Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Right;
                }                                                                                                     'O1' is cell number. can you please assist where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't creating an Excel file at all. It is creating a tab-delimited string which you send to the client using the wrong content type and file extension.

Excel can read delimited files just fine, but can't *guess* what separator or codepage was used to create it. When you open a text file from the "Data" tab, Excel allows you to specify the delimiters, codepages etc. When you double click on the file though, or try to open it directly from the browser (same thing actually), it can't show a dialog and uses your *end user's* regional settings and ANSI codepage.

Creating a real Excel file is actuall a *lot* easier, using a library like EPPlus. You get a real Excel file which also allows you to apply formatting, add charts etc. The result is also a *lot* smaller as `xlsx` is zipped xml.

The library's site already contains [an example that returns a spreadsheet](http://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WebapplicationExample) from the server directly. Removing the custom formatting, it's as simple as:

```
    private void DumpExcel(DataTable tbl)
    {
        using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            //Create the worksheet
            ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Demo");

            //Load the datatable into the sheet, starting from cell A1. Print the column names on row 1
            ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(tbl, true);

            //Omitted formatting code 

            //Write it back to the client
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=ExcelDemo.xlsx");
            Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());
        }
    }
```

Formatting a range of cells or an entire column is also easy

```
//Example how to Format Column 1 as numeric 
using (ExcelRange col = ws.Cells[2, 1, 2 + tbl.Rows.Count, 1])
{
    col.Style.Numberformat.Format = "#,##0.00";
    col.Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Right;
}
```

The example contains similar code to change fonts and colors